# Amazon EMR Hbase, Thrift server dies out

Tags: java, hbase, thrift

I am using EMR for Hbase. I have a python api which asynchronously writes data to Hbase using celery. But every now and then , there are exceptions. 
Sometimes  the exceptions are about Transport Frame and sometimes just broken pipe.
I always have to log into my master and restart the thrift server manually and restart my celery . I also loose on data.

Any solutions to this?

I  wrote a crontab which run every 5 minutes to run the `hbase-daemon.sh start thrift` command but I get an error mail in /var/spool/mail/hadoop that `Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and Java could not be found`.

Comment: Use short connection from server and client rather than long connection.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the thrift logs for any exception?

If you don't find any exception on the logs, then that means that thrift is being killed, and that usually happens on OutOfMemoryError. So basically you just need to add more memory for the thrift server or open less scanners at the same time (scanners consumes huge amount of resources).

As about the JAVA_HOME error, you have to set it for the user hadoop

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/where/java/is
```

Answer (score 0):

If the thrift server is crashing quite often, one reason may be that you are not closing your scanners. So eventually the memory used by thrift goes more than 4-5gb and then it crashes. Close the scanners and  try. Use smem to find out how much memory it is using. Also, there is a log file that is generated, that  almost every time has the reason why an exception was thrown.

this is how you can access the log file in the master:

1. cd hbase\logs
2. ls -lt //Sort the files based on time
3. vi [Name of the log file at the 1st position in the result] //view the log